# MySQL Workbench: Custom fields for Relationships

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to manage an existing DB, created "manually" without mysql-wb.

I want to draw the printable ER diagram.

When I create a relationship, workbench creates its own external key fields.

How can I create the relationship binding to my own fields?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the *Place a relationship using existing columns* option? Using one of the other options will create a new column in the referencing table, which is mostly useful when you're creating new structure.

You can create relationships by editing the table, going to *Foreign Keys*, and adding it there manually, as well.